# Separating UITableView data into sections from one source

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have one table in my core data source which holds some articles with NSDate's. I basically want to separate the NSManagedObject into days, so you can scroll through and separate articles by date.

What is the best way to approach this? My context is queried out in descending date order, so just need to split that up into days for the UITableView sections, rather than 1 big section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the data for your table -- whether that's using `NSFetchedResultsController` and Core Data, or loading a .plist file into an `NSDictionary` object -- you can "section" it as you like.

You'll first step through the data (e.g. use the `fetchedObjects` property if using `NSFetchedResultsController`) and determine what sections you want. Since you're wanting to split on dates, you might store cutoffs represented by `NSDate` objetcts in an array. You would then use this array to implement the various `UITableViewDataSource` methods: in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` you can return the `count` of this array, and in `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` you can return `NSString` representations of those stored `NSDate`s for the section titles.

Methods like `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` are a little trickier. You'll probably want to use another "preprocessed" data structure (perhaps a two-level array of arrays, where the inner arrays contain the entity objects you fetched), and you'll want to set up as the same time as your array of `NSDate` objects.